# How to get http request headers used by SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, http-headers, soap-client

I want to check my http headers that are sent via a [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient).

Yet it only offers quick functions to fetch the Soap headers:

```
/**
 * Returns the SOAP headers from the last request
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequestheaders.php
 * @return string The last SOAP request headers.
 * @since 5.0.1
 */
public function __getLastRequestHeaders () {}
```

I am not interested in those.

How can I find out what http headers have been used for the request on the HTTP level?

Xdebug loses context at the `_call` and the client doesn't seem able to to fetch that information by itself.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Wireshark. I configured my SoapClient to just post against my local IP, for me that was 10.49.57.28.

I captured the `any` interface.

First I had to enable the protocols via: Ctrl + Shift + E. I selected "Enable All".

I used the filter:

```
http.request.method == "POST" and ip.addr == 10.49.57.28
```

I right clicked the relevant request and used:

Follow > TCP Stream

And there I had all the relevant request information:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.49.57.28
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2085
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope ...
```

Of course, the response will be an error, yet I wasn't interested in that.