# Why is my mock Soap Server only returning empty string?

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

This is a follow up in regards to my question about [removing the expect headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608159/how-to-get-http-request-headers-used-by-soapclient).

I have a mock soap server imitating the external endpoint. It was set up by using the default `SoapServer` of php:

```
$server = new SoapServer('http://externalapi.foo/the_wsdl.xml');
$server->setClass(ExternalApi::class);
$server->handle($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

which worked before, once I remove the expect header in the client, I only get an empty response back, no matter the request making my acceptance fail:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 11:18:40 GMT
Server: nginx/1.11.6
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: HHVM/3.15.3
""
```

(The `""` is placeholder for empty text.)

Answer (score 0):

The note, even though downvoted, by [king maxemilian on php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/soapserver.handle.php#77248) pointed me in the right direction. They wrote:

> Sometime, it happens that PHP does not detect anything in
>   `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.`
>
> To solve this problem and make it work in any case:
>
> ```
> function soaputils_autoFindSoapRequest()    {
>     global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
>
>     if($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)
>         return $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
>
>     $f = file("php://input");
>     return implode(" ", $f);
> }
>
> $server = new SoapServer($wsdl);
> $server->setClass($MyClass);
>
> $server->handle(soaputils_autoFindSoapRequest());
> ```

I simplified this for my mock soap server to

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
function findSoapRequest()    {
    $f = file("php://input");
    return implode(" ", $f);
}

$server->handle(findSoapRequest());
```

While this works for me, I have no clue as to why it's happen.